# Dynamic classes import and object building

Tags: python

I have a python package which gathers multiple modules. In those modules, I have multiple classes heriting from a Component class. I'd like to make the load of those classes dynamic and to build some object dynamically.

```
ex: 
package/module1.py
       /module2.py
```

in `module1.py`, there is multiple classes heriting from the class Component, the same with `module2.py`, of course the number of classes and package is unknown. The final user define which object has to be built in a config file. In order to iter throught modules, I use the pkgutil.iter_modules which is working. From my function in charge to build the components, I do like this:

```
[...]
myPckge = __import__('package.module1', globals(), locals(), ['class1'], -1)
cmpt_object = locals()[component_name](self, component_prefix, *args)
[...]
```

However, this is not working as the class is not recognized, the following works but is not dynamic:

```
cmpt_object = myPckge.class1(self, component_prefix, *args)
```

thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

you can use `execfile()` to load modules on the fly and then use `exec()` to create new objects from them. But I dont understand why you're doing this!

Answer (score 0):

To find the subclasses of a class in a specified module, you can do something like:

```
import inspect
def find_subclasses(module, parent_cls):
    return [clazz for name, clazz in inspect.getmembers(module)
        if inspect.isclass(clazz) and
        issubclass(clazz, parent_cls) and
        clazz.__module__ == module.__name__ and  # do not keep imported classes
        clazz is not parent_cls]
```

Note that `parent_cls` doesn't have to be the direct parent of a class for it to be returned.

Then you can dynamically load classes from a module, knowing the module's name and directory, and the parent class of the classes you want.

```
import imp
def load_classes(module_name, module_dir, parent_cls):
    fle, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_name, [module_dir])
    if fle:
        module = imp.load_module(module_name, fle, path, descr)
        classes = find_subclasses(module, parent_cls)
        return classes
    return []  # module not found
```